What kind of impression is likely if a resume contains a BSD licence?
I found a nice LaTeX CV template that I'd like to use. It is licensed under the BSD 3-Clause licence.
Clause 2 states


Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
and/or other materials provided with the distribution.


According to this answer, a PDF generated does count as a binary, and therefore, the licence text must be included with the CV. That answer suggests putting the text in small print at the end of the document, but I suppose the other option would be to include it in a cover letter/email.
I'm curious how potential employers, hiring managers or recruiters might view this. So far I've imagined two possible responses. Perhaps the reader would look upon it favourably, noting that the CV author hasn't reinvented the wheel, but rather saved time and effort by using something that already exists, and they also comply with the license requirements. Alternatively, the reader might see that it's obvious the design was not the author's own, and which might give the impression that the author is lazy.
I'd be interested to hear your thoughts if you hire people, or about any experiences you've had doing this when applying for jobs. Context is Australia, in software development, but I'd be curious to hear about any other contexts as well.

Personally, I would dodge the question by finding another template. It's a needless complication.

I think the opinion you got on law.se is wrong. If you printed the LaTeX source to a PDF and distributed it, that would be a binary.

IANAL but I think you’re focusing too much on the “binary” and ignoring the “redistribution.” A document created using software isn’t a redistribution of said software and the positioning of words on a page probably isn’t novel enough to be considered intellectual property.

It’s nice that you want to give credit to the creator for helping you with your resume but the point is to showcase your work, not someone else’s. Anything that doesn’t serve that purpose only detracts.

The OpenSource Stack Exchange fairly consistently gives the most extreme interpretation of any clause, I agree with @Theodore that the answer given there is wrong: largely because, imo, the pdf is not a redistribution of the template. Perhaps the creators of the template could have chosen a better license to make this clear.


So far I've imagined two possible responses. Perhaps the reader would look upon it favourably, noting that the CV author hasn't reinvented the wheel, but rather saved time and effort by using something that already exists, and they also comply with the license requirements. Alternatively, the reader might see that it's obvious the design was not the author's own, and which might give the impression that the author is lazy.

Frankly, I think neither of those thoughts will cross many readers' minds. Unless you are applying for a graphical design job, I'd wager most people assume you have not created your document design yourself but used a template of whichever text processing software you happened to use. (Sadly, this will even be the case if you have created your own design and put quite some effort into it.)
I would be more concerned about another impression this might give: Even among IT professionals, there is a wide variety of familiarity with what LaTeX is, how it works, and why one would want to use it.
Chances are at least some of the people handling your document are not sufficiently familiar with the package-based nature of LaTeX and wouldn't make the connection that

a PDF generated does count as a binary, and therefore, the licence text must be included with the CV

so the only impression that remains is "that document was written by some weirdo pedant who seriously floods us with legalese text in their application documents for some reason".
In most sanely organized companies, I'd hope this should not lead to a desk reject, and if asked, you can surely make a good case for why you included it - but there is a certain probability for raised eyebrows, plus some interviewers just taking away that you incomprehensibly picked an unsuitable tool for your documents. Unsuitable because you need to include license texts when you don't have to do so while solving the same task (writing down a CV) in MS Word.

It's going to depend a great deal on what sort of person reads it, if they're a big FOSS enthusiast they might be impressed but for everyone else they're going to view it negatively, it's a waste of precious space on a document that needs to convey important info about you and your suitability for the role and to do it as efficiently as possible possible. A licence that is only there because you saved a bit of your time doesn't do that.

Even if properly understood, your CV would be showing both pedantry and misjudgement.
The template itself to which you refer is almost certainly the thing which the creator considers licenced. Not the novel and personalised CV you produce using the stylistic influence of the template.
But even if the product of the template did require a copyright notice, it would simply be foolishness on your part to use that template, rather than creating an original CV of your own stylistic design requiring no licence term to be stated.
Even at a stretch, in jobs where pedantry is appreciated or expected, I think this would be considered going far too far.
It's such extreme and strange behaviour that, frankly, when they look at the notice, I think they'd prefer the explanation that you were grossly careless and included unrelated text in a CV, or that you didn't proofread an automatically-generated document before sending it to them (i.e. the carelessness is yours, and the stylistic quality was all somebody else's).
You might not even get the opportunity to clarify, but if you did, it would be a memorable conversation for them for all the wrong reasons.
My advice firmly is not to include this kind of extraneous legal nonsense in a CV.

Personally, unless this was for an internship position, or unless this was the OP's first job, I would bin the resume.
It's a resume. It doesn't need to be clever. It doesn't need to picture perfect. And it shouldn't be weird like that. A normal seasoned employee would just skip that resume template and find a different one (even a less than perfect one) with no license.
It's important not to be bogged down by such details and not lose track of your larger goal. I've worked with needless perfectionists in the past and I avoid working with such people in general.

If I get a CV with any kind of legalese, it is instantly binned. I want to read about you. Having to worry about some licensing just wastes my time.

What I would do I really needed to (i am not a lawyer, not legal advice)
Flatten and/or Rasterize the documents and store them as PDF/A. Make sure that only the information whith is typeset is in the final file. In that sense you won't redistibute the latex program which generated the file and not a part of the structure but the result of running the program without any Information from inside the program. And you definitely don't redistribute the latex template in that case.
That is, unless there is actual protectable artwork inside the file.

As a Native Brit and now adopted Kiwi - I would have thought breaking the law is still a job requirement in Australia :P
Okay, regional Bants out-the-way:
My first thought is that you should include it. Here is why:

It demonstrates integrity.
It shows an appreciation for process
It shows an ability to leverage existing tools to your purposes

IMO - these are all good things. For me, the biggest is probably the first point - Integrity.
It is very similar to The Shopping Trolley theory - in short - there is no real downside for you not doing it, there is no real upside for you doing it - but you do it because you know it is the right thing to do.
That, to me, is something I value in other people.
I think your question about laziness though is a little moot. As an IT professional, I care deeply about efficiency. Sometimes spending 20 hours to come up with my own solution that does 100 percent of what I want it to do is absolutely the right call.
Sometimes, using someone elses solution to do 90 percent of it and then I just fill in the blanks for the last 10, spending only 4 hours is the right thing to do.
At worst - this would be something that would be a discussion point in your initial interview - and from there it would simply be a case of how you frame it:

talking about your love of automation, using best-of-breed technologies, looking areas where you can maximize your output whilst minimizing your input = Good

talking about how you hate doing CVs, its a lot of time wasted for something you use rarely etc. = Bad


So put it on - see how you get on.

At least for points two and three I would expect the proper course of action to be "don’t use it", with a high chance of "use MS word instead" (yes, those are real tears rolling into my genuine apple user turtleneck). Picking a tool such as LaTeX with such fineprint on top isn’t "the process" for all but a finite number of organisations, and having to worry about this indicates a poor usage of tooling.

Your dig Australian workers falls flat.  Being able to trace your ancestors back to convict roots is a status symbol. As for me, I'm 100% free settler stock so I am forever looked down upon in that regard.  Although I do have a great-great-..-great-aunt who had an ongoing affair with the original, married, governor of a state. :P
